# sstabledump not found on Cassandra 3.11 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have installed Cassandra 3.11 on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine but I am not able to find `sstabledump` utility in the bin folder.

How can I get this installed as patch? Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which version you have installed:

- DataStax Enterprise 5.0 Installer No-Services and tarball installations:

  > install_location/resources/cassandra/tools/bin
- Cassandra tarball installations:

  > install_location/tools/bin/

For package installations (Cassandra package or DataStax Enterprise 5.0 Installer Services and package installations) you do not need to know the installation folder to run it, you can just simply use it as:

> sstabledump [options]  sstable_file

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/ToolsSSTabledump.html

Also to have the tools, you need to install `cassandra-tools` separately apart from cassandra:

```
sudo apt-get install cassandra-tools
```

Comment: I have used cassandra package installation... # Next, add the Cassandra repository keys:
curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key A278B781FE4B2BDA
when I run sstabledump sstable_file, I get "command not found"

Comment: I checked and it seems the sstabledump utility hasn't been added to the cassandra-tools.install in the cassandra debian install on trunk. There is a JIRA ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11642 which says it will be added from 3.8.
Have you also ran: `sudo apt-get install cassandra-tools` ?

Comment: Thanks!! for the cassandra-tools install. Now I see the sstabledump binary inthe bin directory. sstabledump mc-1-big-Data.db now gives error ...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.newPartitioner(FBUtilities.java:411)
 at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.metadataFromSSTable(SSTableExport.java:102)
 at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:178) ... the table is simple with 5 rows. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: IT STARTED WORKING !!! I did not do any changes to the config file etc. Just gave cassandra VM a rest of 30 minutes after installing cassandra-tools..... works !!

Comment: I also updated my answer to have all the important parts of the answer together.

Comment: This question seems to be a separate topic. Please post it as a new question, you can link it here, if you want. Also if your problem solved, you can accept this answer.